# How to get an element that has a dynamic selector in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

My script has a button which leads to an external site where I need to input some information in a field.

I'm not able to find a way to select that field because it's within an iframe and also has a dynamically generated ID. That ID has 2 characters at the end that are **always consistent**.

So far I've tried:

`cy.get('#*_2');` --> Trying to use a wildcard to click on the element that has a  _2 at the end but it does not work

I've tried using a `cy.get('input[data-collect-as="input"]')` --> It's not able to find this element either.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorthand id selector `#myid` can only be used with the exact value, but `id` is still an attribute so you can use an attribute selector with a wildcard

```
cy.get('[id$="_2"]')         // $= means value ending with
```

There's a bunch variations, see [Selectors - Attribute](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

---

The other approach you tried should work like this

```
cy.get('div[data-collect-as="input"] input')
```

This gets a child `input` with ancestor `div[data-collect-as="input"]` - the space denoting two separate elements and the relationship is ancestor -> descendant.

You can add more precision

```
cy.get('div[data-collect-as="input"] > div.wrp > input')
```

where the `>` indicates a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern attribute value as well.

```
cy.get('input[pattern="[0=9]*"]')
```